# Fixed head and menu issue

Tags: css, menu, position, fixed, head

We made a fixed head and menu on our site.
But the menu has a little bit of transparency, so basicly the content goes through our menu.

Is there a way to cut it off. So basicly that the content just stops at the menu. 
When you scroll you have a fixed head, but the content won't see through or (at the sides).

Thanks!
URL: http://sea-and-wetest.netserver11.net/

Comment: This seems like a site that doesn't really benefit from the fixed header and menu. While I'm trying to think of a solution to the specific question asked, I still wonder if it'd be best for your particular case to just use the default `static` positioning, at least on this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the background-image comes from an actual  tag.

So, what you could do is add the same image again, with the same css styles except for it's height, which should be equal to the height of the header and menu bar combined, and it should be from a stacking context perspective, below the header and menu bar, but above the content-body.

This is a matter of playing with the order of the elements on the html and choosing the right z-indexs.

Comment: The background image is loaded with jQuery. So it gives an image to the body element. How can I do this on my head element then?

Comment: We decided to remove this feature. It isn't that necessary... Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: I never saw your comment. Sorry, I could have helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>head fixed</title>

<style>

#dvHead {position:fixed;left:19px;top:12px;height:24px;background-color:#d8d7c0;color:#888888;border:1px solid #c4bc8b;}
#dvBody {position:fixed;left:20px;top:38px;height:100px;background-color:#dddddd;overflow:auto;}
td {border:1px solid #c4bc8b;}

</style>

<script>

function initpage() {
resize_thead();
}

function resize_thead() {for(var i=0;i<3;i++){document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].firstElementChild.rows[0].childNodes[i].width=document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1].firstElementChild.rows[0].childNodes[i].clientWidth;}}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="initpage()">

<div id="dvHead">
<table>
<tr><th>TH 1</th><th>TH 2</th><th>TH 3</th></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="dvBody">
<table>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td><td>TD 3</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and "[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" before answering a question.